# Doctrine relation with entity class or type

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm, doctrine

I have entities:

Article: id, title, text

Page: id, title, text

Url: id, url, entity_id, entity_type

URL it’s a place where I store url for each entity, article or page at the moment.

I can easily make it work without doctrine relations. On save I can add new url record, and I can fetch/join url record when it’s needed.

But I wonder if there is any possibility to use doctrine relation for this task. I didn’t found any information in docs about that so I think it’s not obvious.
With JoinColumn I can define only columns without hard coded type, or class name.
The problem is that I cannot create simple OneToOne relation, because there is entity_id and **entity_type** (with value “article” or “page”)

Comment: have you considered adding url_id to article and page, instead of the other way around (or even simpler, just add the url field to article/page)? and if you want multiple urls per article/page, have extra relations page_urls and article_urls where those are mapped to each other. In general, this "entity_type + entity_id" - design prevents foreign key support from the database, and all of this because you don't want to have two relations instead. IMHO, this is *barely* worth only if you want to search for the urls irrespective of entity type, which you can do with little overhead with 2 tables

Comment: I have API with url resolver where i have to return type of url and entity id if needed. It will be widely used for other urls like 301 etc. in the future. That’s why I want to have everything needed for resolving url in separate, one url table

Comment: technically (and only technically) doctrine could do this with exactly your database layout via [Class Tables in Inheritance Mapping](https://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/2.15/reference/inheritance-mapping.html#class-table-inheritance), which would make Url the superclass and Page/Article the subclasses. If you want it clean, you could have article_id and page_id in the url table. In code it's slightly inconvenient sometimes. You could also have bidirectional links and keep the entity_id/type as kind of cache and have url_id in the tables.

Comment: I don’t want to have article_id in url table because this table can have a lot more entities. For know I will leave it without any relations and I hope it will work fine :) thanks for help